# embed twub into facebook iframe

Tags: iframe, embed

I received the embed codes from twub

I placed them in html iframe tab
I just used the Google map template they had and erased some of the code and replaced with mine, here is the result

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Yallerschat</title>
</head>
<body>

 <iframe src="https://twubs.com/embed/yallerschat/?messagesPerPage=5&headerBgColor=%231c6485&headerTextColor=%23ffffff" width="350" height="600" frameborder="0"><a href="https://twubs.com/yallerschat">#yallerschat</a></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

I even added the "s" in "http". This source comes up blank when I click on preview or from Facebook tab. Not sure what am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated and YES you can laugh...

Comment: I can load the page, so that's not the problem. I can't see what's your problem. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: im on facebook and the tab shows up blank- like nothing comes up

Comment: Which tab do you mean?

Comment: it keeps telling me to configure-even after i know it has been set up-not sure what i am doing wrong.. i am in the thunderpenny ifram editor.. set up all the info and nothing

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong either. I don't even know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Remember this site is about programming and is not a support forum for Thunderpenny or Facebook. Please update your question with some information what you're trying to do and what's exactly your problem. Maybe your browser's console can give you debug information.